# Create new string field and replace numbers from other field with text

Tags: qgis-3, field-calculator, fields-attributes

I would like to create a string field in a shapefile where the string expression is dependent on the numbers given in another field. For example if there is a '1' in the source field there should be the expression 'Kontrolle' in the string field; if there is a '2' in the source field there should be the expression 'Kontrolle Baumkolonne' and so on.
Can I realize this in the field calculator?

Comment: Have a look at `CASE WHEN` - the explanations in the help window in the field calculator are rather helpful.

Comment: Yes, the CASE WHEN will be suitable. But how can I define several CASE WHEN conditions, so that for every number there will be an entry?

Comment: `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... WHEN ... THEN ... WHEN ... THEN .......... (ELSE) END`

Comment: You can also create a value table , add two columns one for the 1,2,3,4... and one with 'Kontrolle', 'Kontrolle Baumkolonne'... Then join the value table to the shapefile and add a new field using field calculator

Answer (score 2):

You can edit a table with the single combination of the two value es:

```
 ID   Name
 1   Kontrolle
 2   Kontrolle Baumkolonne
```

Then you can do a Join with your data using the 'ID' attribute.

After this you can copy data from joined 'Name' in the field that you want.